# VBA Countif(s) Syntax issue (and/or about multiple conditions)

Tags: vba, syntax, excel, countif

I've looked around the Stackoverflow forums (and basically everywhere else on Google) and have found a lot of "almost" answers to my questions that would probably suffice if I was a bit more familiar with VBA, but I've messed around with it for a while and haven't been able to sort out. Getting a little frustrated, so I figured it was time to ask! Sorry if I get verbiage etc. wrong when explaining my issue! It's probably just a problem with my syntax.

Basically I need to be able to take data from a column in a spreadsheet and have it do a Countifs (I think anyway) of cells of a specific set of parameters. All of the data I need would be page dimensions with the format of "Dimension1 x Dimension 2" e.g. "8.5 x 11"

```
Valtest = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("P:P"), "8.5 x 11")
```

This formula, probably rather unsurprisingly, works just fine. But I need the countifs (or whatever I need) to also be able to give me dimensions <= 8.5 x <=11 as well as flipping the dimensions (<=11 x <=8.5).

I've tried changing the formula to formats like (and similar)

```
Valtest = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("P:P"), "<=8.5" & " x " & "11")
```

But that will report a dimension such as 3 x 4 or 22 x 11. I know countifs can use multiple parameters (which is why I was messing around with it instead of just a normal countif), but I don't know if entering multiple arguments is even the correct path or if it's something with quotations being used correctly or... who knows?

I was able to make an If-then statement work alright (using an array and cycling through each cell with a counter) but this is clearly not the fastest way to do this. Here it is, just for the sake of making my goal a little clearer.

'If x(0) <= 8.5 And x(1) <= 11 Or 
x(1) <= 8.5 And x(0) <= 11 Then

In a related issue, I'd also need to be able to find pages that are, for example, <=11 x <=17 or something while not including search results for my previous question (8.5 X 11). So I need to know the proper syntax for multiple parameters that would involve saying something like <8.5 but less >=17.

Thanks in advance! Any help is quite appreciated. Let me know if I haven't explained anything adequately.

Edit: An example of data I would be searching:

```
A                     Count for 8.5 x 11 (expected output)
8.6 x 11              5
8.5 x 11  
8.5 x 11  
8.5 x 11  
8.5 x 11  
8.4 x 11  
22 x 11  
10 x 17
```

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your columns data that you are trying to validate?

Comment: Sure. A column might have data something like: 
8.6 x 11
8.5 x 11
8.5 x 11
8.5 x 11
8.5 x 11
8.4 x 11
22 x 11

Comment: You said you also "need to find pages".. So what are these corresponding `pages` that you are asking to find? It's best just updated your questions by appending a part of your columns :) cut paste would do. I updated your data, can you tell us is that what you have , a corresponding page name in the next column?

Comment: I would just want the total/result of the countifs statement output to another cell on the worksheet. So in the data I used as an example, I'd want to find every page <=8.5 x <=11 and get the answer (5) reported to another cell.

Comment: @ boncodigo The format you've edited in would be fine. The end result of this is that I would like to be able to take a great deal of this page size data, paste it into a column of a spreadsheet and have excel tell me how many pages fit in the 8.5 x 11 parameter in one cell, the 11 x 17 parameter in another cell. etc.

Comment: @Tim Williams That is a bit beyond my current grasp of VBA (for example, I don't even know what a UDF is). It may be a solution! I'll have to mess around with it sometime today and try to sort it out. Thanks regardless. Once I know if it works, I'll post a response.

Comment: Just another thought, based on this line `If x(0) <= 8.5 And x(1) <= 11 Or x(1) <= 8.5 And x(0) <= 11 Then`. You are checking if both dimensions for the same parameters. That simply says you could check the `Area`, in this case `8.5 * 11 = 93.5` ;) BTW `UDF` is a User define function.

Comment: @bonCodigo The problem just making it a calculation of area is that if the dimensions of the page exceed certain size, then the results I'm trying to get wouldn't be valid (for example, i could potentially have page dimension of 4 x 23.375) and that would not be alright to be included in the 8.5 x 11 report. Also, would I just use this UDF like any other formula and paste it alongside the column of my data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this UDF: copy and paste to a regular VBA module.  You pass it a range, and lower/upper bounds for the small and large dimensions respectively.

Eg: to count all sizes with small side between 8 and 10 and large side between 12 and 14 (inclusive):

```
=CountSizes(A:A,8,10,12,14)
```

EDIT: for your specific use case of 8.5x11 or smaller

```
=countsizes(A:A, 0, 8.5, 0, 11)  'one side btw 0 and 8.5 & one side btw 0 and 11.5
```

EDIT3: to show how you'd use this from VBA instead of as a UDF, including your second column

```
Sub Tester()
    With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Pages")
        'count only where second column has "Color"
        .Range("B1").Value = CountSizes(.Range("A:B"), "Color", 0, 8.5, 0, 11)
    End With
End sub
```

Code:

```
Function CountSizes(rng As Range, colorType As String, _
                     smallGE, smallLE, largeGE, largeLE)

    Dim tmp, val, v1, v2, small, large, arr, arrVals
    Dim num As Long, r As Long, nr As Long

    num = 0
    arr = rng.Value
    nr = UBound(arr, 1)
    For r = 1 To nr
        val = Trim(arr(r, 1))
        If val Like "*x*" Then
            arrVals = Split(val, "x")
            v1 = Trim(arrVals(0))
            v2 = Trim(arrVals(1))
            If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
                v1 = CDbl(v1)
                v2 = CDbl(v2)
                If v1 > v2 Then
                    small = v2: large = v1
                Else
                    small = v1: large = v2
                End If

                If small >= smallGE And small <= smallLE And _
                   large >= largeGE And large <= largeLE Then

                    If Trim(arr(r, 2)) = colorType Then
                        num = num + 1
                    End If

                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next r

    CountSizes = num
End Function
```

Comment: In using your UDF and your example (placing my data in column A) I'm just getting a result of 0. I'm guessing there's something I'm just not understanding?

Comment: Looks like that is working perfectly. Thanks very much. Is there an equivalent way to adapt this into a non-UDF? I realize I'm splitting hairs, it's more for my curiosity at this point. Basically have this happen, but have the result be placed into a specific cell without having to enter the formula? I'd like others to be able to use this after just pressing a button or something. Thanks.

Comment: It would work equally well as a regular function - you could just call it from another Sub. I will edit the answer to show that.

Comment: Yeah. I started sorting that out myself. Thanks again. You and @bonCodigo have been a big help. Thanks to both of you. Hopefully what I was working towards looks like the edit you're going to make! heh.

Comment: Okay! One more, unfortunately! Let's say I have another column in the same spreadsheet. It coincides with each dimension entry, and it will either be "Color" or "B/W" So A:A would be the the dimensions you already sorted for me and B:B would one of those two. How would one go about getting this current macro to report into two separate cells? One for the color and one for the b/w. Thanks again.

Comment: See edit 3 - if you have any more variations then you should probably start a new question.

Comment: Yeah. I wasn't sure what the best practice was for that. Thanks again for your help.